# EC2 is not responding for ssh connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Another bad day. I have all the configuration for my ec2 instance.
Till yesterday I was able to connect it via ssh on mac. but know why it's not getting connect now.

Configuration is as below:
[image: ec2 configuration]

Security Group:-
[image: inbound]
[image: Outbound]

I'm using below steps as usual and I'm same directory where mypleaks-inst.pem kept.[image: connect]

Comment: try to add ipv6 for ssh connection

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan its working now, don't know how but just after adding http 80 port in inbound it started working

Comment: sure why not...

Answer (score 0):

My guess: Your security group that was applied was "launch-wizard-2" which by default sets exlusion rules. You need to associate that EC2 instance with one of the two security groups listed in your second screen shot to allow TCP connections on port 22 from inbound ip range. OR you could modify launch-wizard-2 to incorporate the relevant rules to allow for ssh connection.

Comment: These details are of "launch-wizard-2" only. :(

Comment: So are you saying those are the inbound and outbound rules of launch-wizard-2 sg?

Comment: Yes, correct. And now I just added http with 80 port in the inbound rule and it's working now. don't know what is the connection between ssh and http port. see updated inbound screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure nothing was changed on AWS side then perhaps your SSH service is down temporarily or permanently (the server was overloaded? You can do it with ease with T2.small).
Check NACL and routing, otherwise.